# Multisite - channel fields do not work in child template pages

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager, channel

Using expression engine multi-site.

we have a master site "master-site" & a slave/child site "slave-site".

I am creating a new channel "blogs" & it's channel fields.

1) Create "blogs" channel & channel fields from "slave-site" admin panel.

Issue: Only default channel tags "{title}", "{entry_id}" etc are working in templates. If we create a new channel fields then tags for these channel fields do not work in template and shows tags as it is in browser.

Eg: If we create a channel field "blog_description" and using "{blog_description}" tag in template but in browser tag not fetching it's value and showing tag "{blog_description}".

2) Create "blogs" channel & channel fields from "master-site" admin panel.

Issue: "blogs" channel & channel fields are not appearing at "slave-site" admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

Add  channels  so  all  from  the  original  site  are  present,  then  in  `exp_channels`  table  in  the  DB  manually  set  the  field  group  for  each  to  be  the  same  as  the  corresponding  channel  in  the  original  site.